# Can I get Essential Matrix from Fundamental matrix with few matching keypoints, but without intrinsic parameters?

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, camera-calibration

Firstly I guess this question might be duplicated, but I couldn't find it.

Question. It's actually in the title.

- Can I get Essential Matrix from Fundamental matrix with few matching keypoints, but without intrinsic parameters?

Situation. I am trying to find Essential matrix. I use my phone camera to take photos, and then extract keypoints using SIFT(or ORB). I have 2 images of an object and it's matching points. I could get F, Fundamental Matrix but I have no idea how to get Essential Matrix from this.
I don't have camera intrinsic parameters, such as Fx, Fy, Cx, Cy.
I am stuck to this situation. I googled but couldn't get answers.
Let me know if it's duplicated then I'd delete this.

PLUS: I also don't have camera coordinates or world coordinates.

Comment: You only can (and probably need to) guess interior parameters. Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014376/what-do-i-do-with-the-fundamental-matrix/59028162#59028162)

Comment: Thank you, @Grillteller ! It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, you need to know the metric size of the pixel and the focal because essential matrix is in the real world.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask what matrix size of the pixel means? Focal: maybe you mean the focal length of the lens, for example 50mm, right?

Comment: metric not metrix sorry. Thinking more about it you should calibrate your camera, you can do it with opencv.

Comment: Okay. I am going to find ways to calibrate my camera :) Thank you @mathieu.letombe